# Compare values cell by cell in different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have created the following loop for comparing cell values in different worksheets.

```
    Dim mRng, qRng As Range
    Dim i, j As Range
    Dim k As Integer

    With Worksheets("Content")
        Set mRng = .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D2").End(xlDown))
    End With


    With Worksheets("Book")
        Set qRng = .Range(.Range("H2"), .Range("H2").End(xlDown))
    End With


    For Each i In mRng
        For Each j In qRng

            If i <> j Then
                i.Interior.Color = vbRed
                MsgBox "Data does not match, please check again!", vbOKOnly
                Exit Sub
            Else:
                i.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```

How can I modify the above codes so that 'i' will also loop together with 'j' each time (i.e. i2 vs j2, i3 vs j3).

Comment: So you want to check column D2 = H2. then next row, D3=H3?

Comment: Yes I would like to check column D2 = H2 and so on, could u further explain how can I use "i" for both, as currently the  "i "represents each range object in the Worksheets ("contents") @mooseman

Comment: Yeah, after looking at your code more, I notice you use i and j as cell reference and an exit sub if you find non-matching values if i<>j then exit sub?  Does D2 have to equal H2 or can it equal any row in H?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `long` not a range and iterate on that.

```
    'you need to put as type after each variable
    Dim worksheet1 As Worksheet, worksheet2 As Worksheet 
    Dim i As Long, lr As Long

    Set worksheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Content")
    Set worksheet2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Book")
    With worksheet1
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row
    End With
    With worksheet2
        'make sure the second sheet isn't longer than the first
        If .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row > i Then 
            lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    End With
    With worksheet1
        For i = 1 To lr 'iterate the row
            If .Cells(i, 4).Value <> worksheet2.Cells(i, 8).Value Then
                .Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = vbRed
                MsgBox "Data does not match, please check again!", vbOKOnly
                Exit Sub
            Else
                .Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```